# How should I know which kernel options to use?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration

When solving a problem, requires enabling kernel options e.g. with menuconfig. How do I know which to enable/disable?

Comment: Please provide the full details.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I don't have a specific problem. I'm asking about where I can find this information. I know menuconfig has a short description for most options, but it's usually not enough to understand what the option fully does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally Google for it. Sometimes I even check the corresponding patches to understand what the option is about. There's no central place or authority which has this information.

The kernel GIT tree, GIT logs and LKML are the primary means/sources of getting information about kernel options/features:

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/ (mirror: https://github.com/torvalds/linux )
- https://lkml.org/
- https://lwn.net/